# WinForms DataGridView - how to add a row with the Add New Row row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Super simple question here I'm sure - but YouTube has been no help... and I'm pretty dense. Hopefully someone can put me out of my misery in no time.

I have a WinForms DataGridView (using C#) with the Add New Row row along its bottom. It's bound to a data table but that's not really relevant to my question.

All I want is to know which event fires when a new row is added using the Add New Row row - so that I can then check the cell contents and update the data source myself. Yes that may not be the most efficient way to do it. But please humour me. After all, this should be a snap... shouldn't it?

Every YouTube video I've seen uses separate text boxes and a button to add new rows. Easy peasy. The only one I've found which uses the Add New Row row is: *"Insert Update and Delete in C# DataGridView"* by CodAffection. It certainly works (thank goodness!) but he uses the CellValueChanged event (about twenty minutes in).

His data source has an Id column and he uses <datagridview_Name>.CurrentRow to check it. If it's 0 then he knows that a new row is being added and if it's not 0 then a row is being edited instead. Then he gets the cell values, creates a SQL INSERT or UPDATE statement and whoosh - it's all good.

That's what I want but... this strikes me as counter-intuitive to say the least - and what if your data has no Id column? There must be a more appropriate way, right?

Since then I have tried the following events with no joy:

CellBeginEdit

CellContentClick

CellEndEdit

CellEnter

CellLeave

CellValuePushed

Leave

RowValidated

RowValidating

UserAddedRow

RowsAdded

RowLeave

Oh and also, the IsNewRow property isn't at all what one would expect!

I'm running out of events to check, regarding something which one would think would be quite common and straight forward.

I've looked on Stack Overflow... a lot. But couldn't find the answer I'm looking for. Perhaps that's because I'm not asking the right search questions? Regardless, I have finally had to give up and ask for directions!

I will use the CellValueChanged event and fudge it if I must. But if anyone can name the event fired when a new row is added by the Add New Row row then I'd be extremely grateful!

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can see which row is the new row in the DataGridView by checking its NewRowIndex property and comparing the row of the edited cell. Then you still would need to check when a cell value changes.  Does this help?

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Update the balance column whenever the value of any cell changes.
    if (e.RowIndex == DataGridView1.NewRowIndex) {
    // do your thing
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples

Comment: Hi Grant, thanks very much for replying! It's not quite the solution I was hoping for though.

As soon as I type into the "Add New Row" row, another "Add New Row" row appears underneath.

Once I finish typing and press TAB, e.RowIndex is the index of the row I just typed into and DataGridView1.NewRowIndex is the index of the *new* "Add New Row" row.

The example you linked too was extremely helpful though, thanks very much. Not for my question but it showed me things I never knew you could do with a DataGridView!

My data has an Id field so I'll just check if that's zero. Thanks again!